# MediaManager is already initialized

Tags: java, android, cloudinary

I want to upload image to Cloudinary. I have done this with firebase and it works well. But, the client wants Cloudinary.

I am passing byte-array as seen below

```
    val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    capture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
    val data = outputStream.toByteArray()

    val config = HashMap<String, String>()
    config.put("cloud_name", "carflux")
    MediaManager.init(requireContext(), config)

    val uploadRequest = MediaManager.get().upload(data).unsigned("of6bplnq")
        .option("resource_type", "image")
        .maxFileSize(5 * 1024 * 1024)
    uploadRequest.dispatch(requireContext())
```

I get the error `MediaManager is already initialized`

I have checked thoroughly I have only initialized it at a place.

Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The initialization should take place only once, you should call the init() function on the application level and not on an activity level.

Comment: thank you @Michalk

Answer (score 0):

**KOTLIN**
i fixed it by making a static object and making a function to start thr Instance if not initialized.

**The Object **

```
object ApplicationObject{
    private var mediaManager: Any? = null

    fun startMediaManager(context:Context){
        if (mediaManager == null){
            val config = HashMap<String, Any>()
            config["cloud_name"] = "socialseller"
            config["secure"] = false

            mediaManager = MediaManager.init(context, config)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Pass Application Context Only
**In Activity**

```
ApplicationObject.startMediaManager(this.applicationContext)
```

**In Fragment**

```
ApplicationObject.startMediaManager(requireContext().applicationContext)
```